# php db access in all files without include

Tags: php, database, pdo

I am working on a PHP site where DB connections work like this:

index.php: 
  -> includes a file with a db pdo singelton class for db connection
  and after that it includes php files from subfolders whatever a
  user has chosen.

every included php file can use the db class for db connection with:

```
$objDb = Database::getInstance()->getConnection();
```

So far so good. But the include PHP files send ajax requests to other php files in those subfolder, which are not included into index.php. Means in every such a php file I have again include the db connection class (because it does not get it from the index.php).

This is not dramatic, because it´s only a one liner. But I´m asking me if there is a more efficient way of db connection design. Would it maybe be possible to pass the included class to all php files in the subfolders which need a db connection?

Thanks a lot 
Kind regards,

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a file in root dir like `common.php` which should be included in all php files.

In common.php I would create autoloader like in this examples: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php
which would automagically load needed classes without need to include them everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, is this the way bigger systems like drupal or typo3 handling db connections?

Comment: Actually drupal is redirecting all requests to index.php (using mod_rewrite) and uses inside routing system to pass actions to the defined controller. It's also the way wordpress works and many similar CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but not recommended and pointless.

Database connection is only a subcase of general case of configuration.
In your scripts you need many configuration options, constants, initiations and such - so, you need to include a config/bootstrap file anyway.
There you can include your connection line as well.